# MS Access VBA - Using SELECT INTO to create a new table and add a record

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to take a record from another table [Process Order] and put it into a new table with the date on it (NewTableName), but I keep getting 'Too few parameters. Expected 1'. I got it to work and pass one field over based on the [Process No] = txtProc or something earlier but can't get it to pass all the fields I need.

```
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim NewTableName As String

 NewTableName = "[Process Order-Oven " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "]"

 strSQL = "SELECT [Run No], [Product ID], [Process No], [Product Description], " & _
          "[Good Product Produced] INTO " & NewTableName & _
          " FROM 'Process Order' WHERE [Process No] = txtProc.Value"

 CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to build a query first using the query designer to mimic what you want to accomplish.Then,copy the SQL statement that Access generated into VBA and make the necessary adjustments for the table name and any other necessary modifications.

Comment: Why? Making new tables based on dates is really bad design. What is the business need that is causing you to want to create a new table every day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need to concatenate the txt value. I hope it is a Number. If not enclose it between single quotes.

```
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim NewTableName As String

 NewTableName = "[Process Order-Oven " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "]"

 strSQL = "SELECT [Run No], [Product ID], [Process No], [Product Description], " & _
          "[Good Product Produced] INTO " & NewTableName & _
          " FROM [Process Order] WHERE [Process No] = " & txtProc

 CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the txtProc.Value from the string so that the value would be supplied - I assume it is a text field, so it is enclosed with quotes. This should solve the "too few parameters" error. I also changed the 'Process Order' to use bracket delimiters.

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Run No], [Product ID], [Process No], [Product Description], " & _
         "[Good Product Produced] INTO " & NewTableName & _
         " FROM [Process Order] WHERE [Process No] = '" & txtProc.Value & "'"
```

Comment: I should add that using a parameter rather than enclosing the txtProc.Value within the string can prevent injection attacks.